# Output Cache Warmup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm thinking of pre-loading a bunch of pages on Application_Start using a background worker, with something like:

```
    private BackgroundWorker _cacheWarmup;
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        _cacheWarmup.DoWork += cacheWarmup_DoWork;
        _cacheWarmup.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void cacheWarmup_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        CacheWarmup.CachePages();
    }

public class CacheWarmup
{
    public static void CachePages()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        var pagesToCache = GetEarlyCachePages();

        foreach (var page in pagesToCache)
        {
            webClient.DownloadString(page);
        }
    }
}
```

So that the pages will cache server-side with the [OutputCache] attribute. This seems a bit ugly though, and I can't find anyone really doing anything similar. So, I suppose my questions are:

1. Is this overkill and/or pointless?
2. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Personally, I think its pointless and putting extra load on your servers for pages that a user may never access. Edit: Windows Vista did a similar thing where it would pre load applications on startup it thought you may use which just resulted in higher ram usage.

Comment: fair point, but I was thinking of doing a selected list of something like "top products", "top categories", etc.